# Arrays copy memory in Solidity

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, arrays

I have this simple code:

```
function restart() public returns (uint256[] ) {
    uint256[] memory result = new uint256[](5);
    result[0] = 10;
    uint256[] memory result1 = new uint256[](5);
    result1 = result;
    result1[1] = 20;
    return result;
}
```

The result final value is : {10,20}. But I wanted for it to just be {10}. Is there a way to copy an array without being a pointer? I basically just want to create a "local" copy of result.
thank you

Comment: Can i see more of your code please? Thanks

Comment: this is the whole code! I just want to create a copy of an array without it being a pointer. I thought that the "memory" keyword would do just what i want.
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

Comment: function restart() public returns (uint256[] ) {
        uint256[] memory result = new uint256[](5);
        result[0] = 10;
        uint256[] memory result1 = new uint256[](5);
        result1 = result;
        result1[1] = 20;
        return result;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Well what you are doing is so strange for me. i think if you want to do this you can take out the result variable from the function memory and put it outside the function in storage.

```
uint256[] public result = new uint256[](5);
   
    function restart() public returns (uint256[] ) { 
        result[0] = 10; 
        uint256[] memory result1 = new uint256[](5); 
        result1 = result; 
        result1[1] = 20; 
        return result; 
        
    }
```

I think the reason for this is that when you make 2 memory variables in a function and assign one to another they both point out to the same location because they are both has been made inside a function and they're both local. So you can't do such a thing.

[Solidity Docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/types.html#data-location-and-assignment-behaviour)

> Assignments from memory to memory only create references. This means that changes to one memory variable are also visible in all other memory variables that refer to the same data.

**I still wait for someone to approve or reject what i have said.**

Answer (score 1):

You can copy element by element

```
function restart() public returns (uint256[] ) {
    uint256[] memory result = new uint256[](5);
    result[0] = 10;
    uint256[] memory result1 = new uint256[](5);

    for (uint i=0; i < 5; i += 1) {
        result1[i] = result[i];
    }

    result1[1] = 20;
    return result;
}
```